# Why is my ~/.profile being executed on opening a terminal?

Tags: .profile, xfce4-terminal

I want some commands to be executed only for login shells so I put them in `~/.profile` but they are being executed for every terminal* window I open.  How do I find out why this is?

I searched `~/.bash*` and `/etc/bash*` for any executions of `~/.profile` and found none.

*xfce4-terminal 0.6.3

Comment: Is this a `gnome-terminal`? if so, did you check the `Run command as login shell` box (under Profile Preferences --> Command)?

Comment: Fixed question to refer to xfce4-terminal 0.6.3

Comment: Interesting behavior. Is there any reference to your `~/.profile` in `~/.bashrc` ? It could be that it is sourced each time.

Comment: I believe xfce4-terminal has a similar setting (under Edit --> Preferences --> General). Does `echo $0` say `bash` or `-bash`?

Comment: ```$ echo $0
-bash
```

Comment: @ steeldriver:  Yes, the box "Run command as login shell" was checked.  Perhaps at sometime in the past, when I was less literate in the role of various startup scripts, I became frustrated and checked that box -- but I don't recall doing so.

Comment: @steeldriver:  please post your answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are a number of possible reasons why this might happen (such as sourcing the `.profile` from inside `.bashrc`), it seems in this case the reason was that the `Run command as login shell` box was checked under the terminal's `Edit` --> `Preferences...` `General` tab.

The giveaway is that `echo $0` shows `-bash` (indicating a login shell) rather than plain `bash`.

Note that `gnome-terminal` has a similar setting, under `Edit` -> `Profile Preferences` --> `Command`.