# non-login shell sources $HOME/[.local/]bin to $PATH and I can't find why

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04, login, environment-variables

OS: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04

I am initially logged in as user carl. I open a shell and echo $0, I get the confirmation that I am in a non-login shell. ("bash", no dash)
But when I then echo $PATH I see that $HOME/.local/bin and $HOME/bin are both sourced, which is neither declared in ~/.bashrc nor in /etc/environment.

The answer from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364311/ubuntu-desktop-why-the-profile-script-is-executed-in-an-interactive-non-login) indicated inheritance from the logged in user.

So I tested a few things:

```
    $ su - root
    $ echo $0
    > -bash
    $ echo $PATH
    > /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    $ su carl
    $ echo $0
    > bash
    $ echo $PATH
    > /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    $ su - carl
    $ echo $0
    > -bash
    $ echo $PATH
    > /home/carl/.local/bin:/home/carl/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    $ su carl
    $ echo $0
    > bash
    $ echo $PATH
    > /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

In this example, after logging in as root, then switching to non-login usershell, the PATH variable is as it should be. Then I check if logging in as carl and then switching to non-login shell as carl inherits the logged in shells variable and it doesn't.

Additional considerations:

- "run command as login shell" is unchecked
- No cross reference in .bashrc to source .profile or any other file
- no .bash_login or .bash_profile files exist
- Reboot changes nothing

I am officially out of guesses and would much appreciate a penguin guru to enlighten me so that I can sleep again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.local/bin` is added by default by `~/.profile` (copied from `/etc/skel/.profile`):

```bash
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

`.profile` is the correct place to change `PATH`, not `.bashrc`.

## No cross reference in .bashrc to source .profile or any other file

No, it's the other way around. `.profile` sources `.bashrc`:

```bash
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Let's go over your example:

```
$ su - root
$ echo $0
-bash # This is a root login shell. It sources /root/.profile
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
$ su carl
$ echo $0
bash # This is a user non-login shell. It sources .bashrc not .profile
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
$ su - carl
$ echo $0
-bash # This is a user login shell. It sources .profile not .bashrc
$ echo $PATH
/home/carl/.local/bin:/home/carl/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
$ su carl
$ echo $0
bash # This is a user non-login shell. It sources .bashrc not .profile
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

If I forcibly (not recommended) use `su` to log in without going through the login shell, I don't get my normal `$PATH` I want:

```
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ su home
Password: 
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ echo $0 # Non-login shell. Didn't get .profile
bash
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ echo $PATH # Missing what I want
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ bash # Start nested shell
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ echo $0
bash
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ exit # Exit nested shell
exit
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ exit # Exit su shell
exit
```

However, if I log in normally, the `$PATH` is supposed to be `export`ed to child shells. When you log in through `su - username` or the GUI, it should source `.profile` to set `$PATH`. Then this variable will be inherited down from your desktop environment's process, then your terminal emulator, then your bash running inside it.

```
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ su - home
Password: 
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ echo $0 # Login shell sources .profile
-bash
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ echo $PATH # I get the path I want
/home/home/.elan/bin:/home/home/bin:/home/home/.cargo/bin:/home/home/kde/src/kdesrc-build:/home/home/.cabal/bin:/home/home/.ghcup/bin:/home/home/.local/bin:/opt/rocm-6.0.0/bin:/home/home/.go/bin:/home/home/.nvm/versions/node/v21.6.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/home/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ bash # Start a subshell
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ echo $0 # .bashrc is sourced again. .profile is NOT sourced. $PATH is INHERITED
bash
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ echo $PATH # I inherit $PATH like I want
/home/home/.elan/bin:/home/home/bin:/home/home/.cargo/bin:/home/home/kde/src/kdesrc-build:/home/home/.cabal/bin:/home/home/.ghcup/bin:/home/home/.local/bin:/opt/rocm-6.0.0/bin:/home/home/.go/bin:/home/home/.nvm/versions/node/v21.6.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/home/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ exit # Exit nested non-login subshell
exit
home@daniel-desktop3:~$ exit # Exit login shell
logout
```

So in a GUI login, the following is a simplified view (ignoring `systemd` details and other processes in between):

- `gdm3` as root

  - `gnome-session` or another DE. ***This sources .profile***

    - `gnome-terminal`. Does not source anything. Inherits `$PATH`

      - `bash`. This is your non-login subshell. It sources `.bashrc` not `.profile`. It inherits `$PATH` from gnome-session via gnome-terminal

        - `bash`. This is a subshell if you type `bash` again. does the same thing as above

For an SSH/`su - username` login (also ignoring PAM details):

- `sshd` as root

  - `-bash` This is your login shell. ***This sources .profile***. It does not directly source `.bashrc` unless `.profile` tells it to

    - `bash` This a non-login subshell if you type `bash` again. It sources `.bashrc` not `.profile`. It directly inherits `$PATH` from `-bash`

      - `bash` This is another nested non-login subshell if you type `bash` another time. It does the same as the other non-login subshell. It inherits `$PATH` from `-bash` via `bash`

This is the intended behavior. Trying to change it may lead to a bug where there are duplicate entries in `$PATH` and it becomes too long.

If you really want the original shorter `$PATH` in a non-login shell, you could add some code in `~/.bashrc` to detect this situation, and parse and remove stuff from `$PATH`.